# Creating a Logarithm Scale with Min, Max and Discrete "steps"

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logarithm

I'm building a scale for generating colors for a map, where various ranges of numbers correspond to colors. In the scale below, the `a`, `b`, and `c` values (along with the min and max) form "steps" or "buckets" corresponding to colors. Anything between `-1` and `min` will be colored `"#ffeda0` in this example, and anything between `min` and `a` will be colored differently:

```
  return [
    "#e7e9e9",
    -1,
    "#ffeda0",
    min,
    "#fed976",
    a
    "#feb24c",
    b
    "#fd8d3c",
    c
    "#fc4e2a",
    max
    "#e31a1c"
  ];
```

This scale will always start an a minimum value, called min, and will end at a maximum value, max. I've currently got a simple linear scale like this:

```
  const min = Math.min(data);
  const range = Math.max(data) - min;
  const step = range / 4;

  return [
    "#e7e9e9",
    -1,
    "#ffeda0",
    min,
    "#fed976",
    min + step,
    "#feb24c",
    min + step * 2,
    "#fd8d3c",
    min + step * 3,
    "#fc4e2a",
    max,
    "#e31a1c"
  ];
```

How could one write a function that, given a minimum, maximum, and the number of steps in a scale (in this case three) output the correct numbers for a *logarithmic* scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A logarithmic scale is linear in its logarithms. So:

```
const min = Math.min(data);
const max = Math.max(data);

const logmin = Math.log(min);
const logmax = Math.log(max);

const logrange = logmax - logmin;
const logstep = logrange / 4;
```

Now where the linear scale has

```
value = min + n * step;
```

the logarithmic scale has:

```
value = Math.exp(logmin + n * logstep);
```

This will work only if both `min` and `max` are positive, because you cannot take the logarithm of zero or a negative number and bcause in logarithmic scale, each value has a constant positive factor to the previous one. You can make this work for negative `min` and `max` by adjusting the signs.

You can do the calculations in other bases, for example 10:

```
const logmin = Math.log10(min);
const logmax = Math.log10(max);

value = Math.pow(10, logmin + n * logstep);
```

Alternatively, you can find the common factor from one step to the next by taking the *n*-th root of the quotient of the min and max values:

```
const min = Math.min(data);
const max = Math.max(data);

const fact = Math.pow(max / min, 1.0 / 4.0);
```

The values are then found by repeated multiplication:

```
value = prev_value * fact
```

or

```
value = xmin * Math.pow(fact, n);
```

Both methods might yield "untidy" numbers even if the scale should have nice round numbers, because the logarithms and *n*-th roots could produce inaccurate floating-point results. You might get better results if you pick a round factor and adjust your min/max values.

Comment: This is great, thanks! And just because this is pretty above my abilities -- do you mind elaborating real quick on how to accomodate negative numbers? My scale needs to be able to go negative, you mentioned adjusting the signs...

Comment: If both numbers are negative, you can use the fomulas above. They are also valid if your max value is smaller than the min value; you'll just "count backwards". I first thought it was necessary to calculate the stap and factor with positive numbers, but it isn't. You cannot have the range cross zero, though. That would give you a negative factor and you'd get alternating +/- values. The argument to log and the base of a fractional power, essentially a root, must not be negative, either.